# Будет ли рекурсивно создаваться ссылка или указатель будет переписываться?

Tags: php

Будет ли забиваться память?

```
  public function recursive(&$a)
    {
        if ($a < 100000000000) {
            $a++;
            $this->recursive($a);
        }
    }
```

//////---------------------------------------------------////////

```
$a    = 1;
$test = new MyClass();
$test->recursive($a);
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не почитать [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.php)?

Comment: @hindmost А что там сказано? Если бы вы привели цитату из указанной ссылки, которая отвечает на вопрос, было бы намного информативней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение передаётся по ссылке, следовательно, память не будет выделяться на каждой операции. Это в теории.

```
$m1 = memory_get_usage(true);

$a    = 1;
$test = new MyClass();
$test->recursive($a);

$m2 = memory_get_usage(true);
var_dump($m2 - $m1); // 0
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
```

На виртуалке и на моей машине проверил. Независимо от размера цикла памяти всегда одинаково выделяется (**это если верить php**).

А вот если смотреть в это время `htop` на виртуальной машине, то памяти съедается очень даже заметно... На 20М итераций виртуалка вовсе повисла:

[image: вывод утилиты htop - вся память съелась]

А, если смотреть `htop` не на виртуалке, а на основной машине - то расход памяти не заметен. Правда тут у меня другая проблема, если поставить число итераций близким к 100к, то падает с ошибкой:

> Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

Всё тестировал через cli.

Comment: огромное спасибо